# Ruby - setting a value in a hash

Tags: ruby

Anyone care to explain why I'm getting an error here:

```
[~]$ irb
>> h = Hash
=> Hash
>> h["a"] = 100
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]=' for Hash:Class
from (irb):2
```

but not here:

```
>> h = {'dog' => 'canine'}
=> {"dog"=>"canine"}
>> h["a"] = 100
=> 100
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to call `Hash.new`. With your code you are assigning the Hash class to h, not an instance of it.

```
irb(main):001:0> h = Hash
=> Hash
irb(main):002:0> h.class.name
=> "Class"
irb(main):003:0> h = Hash.new
=> {}
irb(main):004:0> h.class.name
=> "Hash"
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to write `h = Hash.new` and everything will be ok. Otherwise you are referencing methods for the class, not an instance. This works as you expect it:

```
h = Hash.new
h['dog'] = 5
```